# IIS Logs Straming to Hadoop real time

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-kafka, flume

I am trying to do a POC in Hadoop for log aggregation. we have multiple IIS servers hosting atleast 100 sites. I want to to stream logs continously to HDFS and parse data and store in Hive for further analytics.

1) Is Apache KAFKA correct choice or Apache Flume

2) After streaming is it better to use Apache storm and ingest data into Hive

Please help with any suggestions and also any information of this kind of problem statement.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use either `Kafka or flume` also you can combine both to get data into `HDFS`but you need to write code for this There are Opensource data flow management tools available, you don't need to write code. Eg. `NiFi and Streamsets`

You don't need to use any separate ingestion tools, you can directly use those data flow tools to put data into hive table. Once table is created in hive then you can do your analytics by providing queries.

Let me know you need anything else on this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is it possible for Kafka or Flume to transfer files or transfer data in a current file as data gets created in IIS web server with some delay for 5 mins or so.

Comment: You can use NiFi's component TailFile with 5 mins on the source side https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.TailFile/index.html